# Lost all my data on the harddisk

Tags: data-recovery

I have windows 8 before installing ubuntu 13.04 on my lenovo z580 laptop. While installing ubuntu i have chosen to erase the disk without knowing. I cant find any files of my hard disk. Plese help me. Thank u very much if it is helpful.

Comment: You need data recovery: http://askubuntu.com/questions/286181/how-do-i-recover-my-accidentally-lost-windows-partitions-after-installing-ubuntu

Comment: Since you've not just formatted the partition but also written data to it (installed Ubuntu) it's likely that you'd lose some of your data that have been overwritten. Remember, the more newer files you save to the partition the more data will be overwritten and the lesser will be there for you to recover. So now you should be looking to use the Data Recovery Tools to get back those that are still to be overwritten. These could help you: http://ubuntu-rescue-remix.org, http://www.knopper.net/knoppix/index-en.html

Answer (score 0):

Recovering after a format, since you probably selected "remove windows and install ubuntu", should be able with Easeus Data Recovery Wizard. I have heard its possible, but you must not have written something to it. Never had the problem before but I would give it a try if I were you

Comment: how to use easeus in ubuntu